# Up Navigation not working as expected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activites, lets call them A, B, and C.

I initially have activity A passing data with intent and calling activity B to open, displaying the data passed from activity A.

Now the issue is when I open activity C from activity B, and use the up navigation that I set up by setting activity B as the parent of Activity C in manifest, none of the data is displayed from Activity A in Activity B. If i simply make a button and call finish(); on the button instead, and not use the up navigation, the activity still contains all data from activity A just how I want it in Activity B.

I'm assuming this has to do with the lifecycle of using up navigation? I even tried using the intent from activity B to C by passing data, and then onResult have it return back to activity B, but it seems the onActivityResult is never called when up navigation is clicked. Any ideas? Maybe I can override this up navigation to just call finish(), like my button does, and nothing more?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the parent activities defined at the Manifest, make sure you override the following methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // You code here
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // or getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) if using support actionbar, i.e., for targets < 3.0;
}
```

Now you will be able to catch the action of the "Up" button with the Id `android.R.id.home`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Still does not work how I want it to. The Up Navigation should do nothing more than to call finish();, I just tested this code and it's still returning null exceptions, as where my button that calls finish(); doesnt.

Comment: What does the `NullPointerException` says?

Comment: says NullPointerException on 
    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("photo");

Comment: Which doesn't happen if I just call finish() on a button though... which has to mean it's not just calling finish, but instead reloading the activity without the data from activity A or something.

Comment: because that data it's nullpointerexception on, is the data originally passed from Activity A to B.